# Get Referrer Page without HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to get the referrer page if `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not turned on and you dont have access to the php.ini file?

I used `print_r($_SERVER)` and saw nothing about HTTP_REFERER in the echoed data.

Below is my script to get the referrer site info but now I need to use JavaScript but am not sure how to work it in:

```
<? 
    //ini_set("display_errors","2");
    //ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);
    $last_page = GetHostByName($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    if(strpos($last_page,"fall2011")) {
        echo '<li><a href="'. $last_page  .'" class="navigation-link">Fall 2011</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo $last_page;
    }    
?>
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will only show if the page was reached from another page.  ie.  if you go directly to the page it won't be there.

Comment: I have been linking from another site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible.

Best what you could do is to throw in some JavaScript.

```
var referrer = document.referrer;
```

If you *need* this in the PHP side (and thus the requirement can't be accomplished by JS alone), then you need to let JS send it by Ajax, or add it as a hidden input field of a form, or append as a query string to internal page links. The hard part is associating the right referrer with the requested page in the server side.

Comment: can I save "referrer" to a php variable?

Comment: Truly, you can do it once it arrives in the server side as a request parameter the usual way by either Ajax, or a form submit or a click of an internal link. I think Ajax will be the most handy as it can be executed during page load already. Alternatively you can also let JS write/add an `<img>` element which points to a transparent 1x1 GIF which in turn actually points to a PHP script and pass the referrer as a query string on the URL.